# How to rename a project in VisualSVN or by the client TortoiseSVN (win32 platform)?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

I tried to find any feature seems like 'rename' both on server side and client side but failed, is it possible?

Comment: Is this about renaming the repository name, or something in the repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Check in the project & make sure no-one is using it. Probably a good idea to stop the server.

2) Back up the repository

3) On the server, rename the root project directory to your new name

4) Start the server again, and on the client, check out using the new name.

Do all this at your own risk - I've only tested it with  a local filesystem.

Comment: How to do step 2&3 ? VisualSVN only tell me it is located at  http:// kaminotebook:70/svn/, no actual path. I don't know where it is on my hd

Comment: Well, you installed it, so you should know where you put it.

Comment: I found it! VisualSVN doesn't display the location and it's been a long time that i forget it.
Your solution works like a charm! I'm greatly appreciate it. i ever did it by new a project and transfer all project files but all history lost.

Answer (score 4):

I was searching for a similar answer and was able to piece together this (surprisingly easy) solution.  Assuming, that is, *IF* you have access to login to the actual server (machine) that runs the VisualSVN server.  *And* you're the only dev. working on it (or can easily tell other dev's about the change so they can follow suit).

Server-side:

- Login to said server, open the "VisualSVN Server Manager" (GUI)
- Right there on the home/start page, under "Repositories", click the
  "Import existing repository..."  Specify source & destination (it
  will create new folder for destination).

Client-side (meaning, your computer/folder where you've stored your working-copy project/files & actually work on them in Visual Studio):

- in Windows Explorer, open up said project's folder and right-click, then under "TortoiseSVN" -> click Relocate... ; it will ask for the SVN URL of the new repository, and then prompt you "are you sure?" (say yes).
- Verify that you can view the whole SVN log history, do an SVN-update, etc. (whatever you feel comfortable with)

Server-side:

- Delete (using VisualSVN Server Manager, still) the old repository.

Again, you need to tell all other developers working on this project about the rename, because each one (each 'client') needs to do the SVN Relocate thing.

If that situation doesn't apply, you'd need to delve more into VisualSVN Server admin-tools: http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/reposadmin/maint/

Answer (score 1):

On you client machine:

- right click on the project folder > Repo-browser
- in Repo-browser rename the project
- in your machine, checkout the project with the new name, where you need it
- remove the folder with the old name from your machine

Answer (score 0):

i did not try but in TortoiseSVN there is a Repo-Browser when you right click and you can probably rename the project name here.

Comment: A window pop and said 'Rename item from http://kaminotebook:70/svn/Test
to http://kaminotebook:70/svn/iTest', after that threw an error said 'Repository moved permanently to 'http://kaminotebook:70/'; please relocate'. Nothing changed.

Comment: probably after you renamed, you should call relocate. then write there your new directory path.

Answer (score 0):

Late addition: In the newer version of VisualSVN Server, you can:

1. Expand the list of repositories
2. Right-click the current name of the repo to change
3. Select Rename
4. Read and understand the pop-up warning message
5. Perform Step #4 again
6. Select the YES button
7. VisualSVN Server will handle all of the other SERVER-SIDE steps. Now it's your job to update the users.